# When a user updates an iOS app, does application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: get called?

Tags: ios

I've looked at [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidFinishLaunchingWithOptions%3a) but am still unsure. Will `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` get called again after the user updates their app from the App Store and then launches the app again? As I understand it, this method only gets called on first launch and then again if the user kills the app. But what about after an update from the App Store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to me it is definitely called again. What if your update brings a new implementation right in the mentioned method? So it have to be called.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that app gets killed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785787/does-applicationdidfinishlaunching-get-called-when-application-is-updated-and-l?rq=1