# Does applicationDidFinishLaunching: get called when application is updated and launched first time?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Is `applicationDidFinishLaunching` guaranteed to be called after application is updated?
(when user first launches the updated version.)

In other words, the old version gets killed if it were running in background mode in update process?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. The updater will kill your app before upgrading if it is backgrounded. This needs to happen since updates can often involve locked files and database migrations.